# Triangle Inequality Infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to see if the following is a norm (specifically if it obeys the triangle inequality.) 
$$\|z\|_{X+Y}=\inf\{\|x\|_X+\|y\|_Y: x+y=z\}$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces. However it is known as a general fact that $\inf(f+g)\ge\inf(f)+\inf(g)$. I wonder if the triangle inequality even holds here. Obviously here we assume $X\cap Y\ne\emptyset$ or else this wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Just a comment. $X,Y$ have to be linear subspaces of $Z$ in order for $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{X+Y}$ to makes sense. Then $X \cap Y$ is never empty as it contains at least the zero vector.

Comment: Yes $X$ and $Y$ are linear subspaces of $X+Y$. I guess the intersection part is irrelevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take $z_1,z_2\in X+Y$. Write $z_i = x_i + y_i$.
Then
$$
\|z_1+z_2\|_{X+Y} \le \|x_1 + x_2 \|_X + \|y_1+y_2\|_Y\\
\le \|x_1\|_X + \|x_2\|_X + \|y_1 \|_Y + \|y_2\|_Y.
$$
Taking the infimum over $x_1+y_1=z_1$ and $x_2+y_2=z_2$ proves the triangle inequality.

Comment: You just assumed the triangle inequality in your first step did you not?

Comment: No, just the definition of the norm on $X+Y$ as infimum.